# Cannot resolve to a type

Tags: java, selenium, maven

I have two different projects in which I have two different packages now am importing one package into another.
`import Exceltwo.guruExcel.*;`
I have also added the classPath in the project where I want to import my package but when I am creating an object for the imported class(project) it is showing me an error "Cannot resolve to a type".

*Additional information - These are my maven projects

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xloNA.png)

Comment: We need to see where exactly `Cannot resolve to a type` occurred ?

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44074179/how-to-add-local-project-not-jar-as-a-dependency-to-a-maven-project

Comment: check if there are any maven dependencies missing, try maven update for project by adding missing dependencies to pom.xml

Comment: Okay, so one of the projects in which am trying to import is not a maven project. (It is a normal project with a TestNG XML file). Am I facing issues due to this?

Comment: @cruisepandey I have added a screenshot for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

**I found the solution by myself**

There were following errors that I was doing here:

1. First, I was trying to import a maven project into a non-maven project.
2. Secondly, I was importing a default package. (Just avoid doing that!)
3. I was adding the Class folder in my java build path. (Instead, go to Build path > configure build path > Projects > Add (add your desired project here which you wish to import))

Hope someone will find it useful!!